# Add Data-Label to GWT-DataGrid

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid

I want to add a data label to my datagrid cells. But I don't have any idea how to access a  element and add a style atribute to it?

Do you have any ideas?

Edit: Goal is to create responsive tables like 
http://codepen.io/maddesigns/pen/pHqnt

```
<table class="responsive">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Vorname</th>
          <th scope="col">Straße</th>
      <th scope="col"><abbr title="Postleitzahl">PLZ</abbr></th>
          <th scope="col">Ort</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
<tr>
    <td data-label="Name">Shannon</td>
    <td data-label="Vorname">Cheyenne</td>
    <td data-label="Straße">Ap #239-2170 Phasellus Av.</td>
    <td data-label="PLZ">94075</td>
    <td data-label="Ort">Berlin</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what do you mean by add a data label? do you want to style all the table cells? can you post a part of your code?

Comment: Like `<tr>
 <td data-label="name">Lindsey</td>
 <td data-label="forename">Tanner</td>
 <td data-label="street">511-635 Malesuada Rd.</td>
 <td data-label="PLZ">77791</td>
 <td data-label="city">Beaconsfield</td>
</tr>`

Answer (score 0):

All that you can do is add style name instead of data-label. 
To do that, you need to have in java code own customCellTableBuilder and in the part of code where you are creating columns add style name like "address" or "name" etc.

Chcek this
 http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractCellTableBuilder.html

Comment: actually you can an attribute to a TD element http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/builder/shared/ElementBuilderBase.html#attribute(java.lang.String,%20int)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to extend the `AbstractCellTableBuilder` by copying the code of the `DefaultCellTableBuilder` and editing it a little.

In the method `buildRowImpl` you will find this code:

```
  // Build the cell.
  HorizontalAlignmentConstant hAlign = column.getHorizontalAlignment();
  VerticalAlignmentConstant vAlign = column.getVerticalAlignment();
  TableCellBuilder td = tr.startTD();
  td.className(tdClasses.toString());
```

Here you could add an attribute to your `td` element like this:

```
String dataLabel = "";
switch (curColumn) {
case 0: dataLabel = "Name";
    break;
case 1: dataLabel = "Vorname";
    break;
case 2: dataLabel = "Straße";
    break;
case 3: dataLabel = "PLZ";
    break;
case 4: dataLabel = "Ort";
    break;
default:
    break;
}
td.attribute("dataLabel", dataLabel);
```

Dont forget to actually use your Builder within your `DataGrid`:
`yourGrid.setTableBuilder(tableBuilder);`

Another example how to use a `AbstractCellTableBuilder` you can find [here](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCustomDataGrid).